how could I write a pytorch model in diamond inheritance way?
I need to implement a complex model, and I better to use Diamond inheritance to satisfy different requirements, here is the toy code to show what I am trying to do:
import torch
import torch.nn as nn
import torch.nn.functional as F
import torch.utils.model_zoo as modelzoo
import torch.distributed as dist



class A(nn.Module):

    def __init__(self, ratio=4, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__()

        self.conv_base = nn.Conv2d(3, 3 * ratio, 3, 1, 1)


class B(A):

    def __init__(self, b_args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(ratio=4)

        self.conv1 = nn.Conv2d(4, 3, 1, 1, 0)


class C(A):

    def __init__(self, c_args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(ratio=4)

        self.conv2 = nn.Conv2d(4, 3, 1, 1, 0)


class D(B, C):

    def __init__(self, b_args, c_args):
        super().__init__(b_args=b_args, c_args=c_args)

        self.conv3 = nn.Conv2d(4, 3, 1, 1, 0)


b_args = dict(a=1)
c_args = dict(b=2)
model = D(b_args, c_args)

I got the error that:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "tmp.py", line 95, in <module>
    model = D(b_args, c_args)
  File "tmp.py", line 88, in __init__
    super().__init__(b_args=b_args, c_args=c_args)
  File "tmp.py", line 72, in __init__
    super().__init__(ratio=4)
TypeError: C.__init__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'c_args'

Would you please tell me how could I make this work?
By the way, I need B and C to be workable, which means that they are not only parents of D, but also a class that should be able to be instanced.

I found a way to overcome the diamond inheritance by explicitly calling the __init__ of the parent class (not by calling from super()) like the below example:
import torch
import torch.nn as nn
import torch.nn.functional as F



class A(nn.Module):

    def __init__(self, ratio=4, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__()

        self.conv_base = nn.Conv2d(3, 3 * ratio, 3, 1, 1)


class B(A):

    def __init__(self, b_args, **kwargs):
        A.__init__(self, ratio=4)

        self.conv1 = nn.Conv2d(4, 3, 1, 1, 0)


class C(A):

    def __init__(self, c_args, **kwargs):
        A.__init__(self, ratio=4)

        self.conv2 = nn.Conv2d(4, 3, 1, 1, 0)


class D(B, C):

    def __init__(self, b_args, c_args):
        B.__init__(self, b_args=b_args)
        C.__init__(self, c_args=c_args)

        self.conv3 = nn.Conv2d(4, 3, 1, 1, 0)


b_args = dict(a=1)
c_args = dict(b=2)
model = D(b_args, c_args)

You will need to explicitly define the parent class for each children class from the moment diamond inheritance start.
